# Customized WordPress Template Sections

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have been working with WordPress for a while, developing custom themes since I have started working with the CMS a number of years ago. Until now, I have used the classic editor, and on each page, added a single section that pulls `the_content()`, and anything else that needed to be added to the page was in that page's template. This meant that most of the content lived in the code itself, and when dealing with clients, anything that they needed changed would have to be sent over, updated in the file(s) and re-uploaded to the server. As you can imagine, with more clients, this gets very tedious and many clients would like to be able to edit this themselves.

### What I am trying to accomplish

I would ideally like a way of creating multiple wysiwyg editors on a single page, having them be tied to some kind of identifier, and imported into the page template. I am trying to do this, because with most of my website designs, there are different sections that go in different orders. For example, if I create a page that has a hero image, then a content section, then another section that would be coded in the template, then another content section that would need to be added that can be edited via the page editor.

This is done for many different reasons, many times it would be because the section in between the content is something that the end user should not be touching.

I know that it can *all* be done in the new block editor, however that can be very tedious, as every item would need special CSS classes added, and any change that the client may make, could break the page very easily.

Essentially, I would like to have multiple sections on the page that I control the layout, styles and javascript in the template itself, and allow users to just fill in or adjust appropriate content in the respective editors.

### What I have tried

I frequently use the [Custom Post Types plugin](https://totalpress.org/plugins/custom-post-types) which is great for things that are generic across the website. I have even used this to apply a post type to all pages, which can be shared across every page and pulled into the appropriate page template in the code. However, as far as I am aware, this cannot be applied only to specific pages, and in certain scenarios I would need to add many custom post types to all pages that could optionally be filled in, which could be confusing for the user. It can be applied to all pages like so [image]

I have only recently started using the new block editor (I was always just installing the classic editor plugin), so I may just be missing something that allows this to all be accomplished here. This also raises some difficulties because even in the block editor, I have tried creating reusable blocks, but that also saves the content itself and not just the layout of what I am trying to create.

### Example page layout

```
<section class="main-content">
  <main class="content">
    <!-- Main content editor -->
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <div class="custom-content">
      <p>Some additional content that does not go in the editor</p>
    </div>
  </main>
  <aside class="sidebar">
    <?php the_sidebar(); ?>
  </aside> 
</section>
<section class="second-section">
  <div class="foo">
    <p>Some content</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="secondary-content">
  <div class="bar">
    <!-- Second content editor specific to this page -->
    <?php the_content('secondary'); ?>
    <div class="custom-content">
      <p>Some additional content that does not go in the editor</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I appreciate any advice and hope there is a solution out there that can solve this use case!